# Redirect to other pages in localhost and website is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

In localhost:
It first comes to that default page in there i will redirect to this(code below)

```
 protected void Page_init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         Response.Redirect("~/Contents/");
    }
```

This works fine for localhost but in the case of webhost:
it comes to www.xyz.com and stops.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Do you receive any errors, either server or client side? Have you tried watching the traffic with a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see if the HTTP 301 Redirect is going through successfully?

Comment: No..i tried in Fiddler  HTTP 301 Redirect is not happened

Comment: Are you sure you're on the correct page? Perhaps the server is configured differently so you're not arriving on the page you think you're on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URL that is passed to the browser doesn't exist, so you're getting a redirect to a other site page instead.

You can use tool called Fiddler. This sits as a proxy between your Web server and your browser and issues a trace of what requests and responses are made.